# create a new data frame with columns from another data frame based on column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

Data frame A exists.

I want to create Data frame B and insert certain columns from data frame A in Data frame B.

I do not want to use the column numbers but the column names to do that

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: `insert certain columns`  Those certain columns have to be either identified by index or the actual column names itself `dataB <- dataA[, c("col1", "col3", "col5")]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the subset of column names if there are no  patterns

```
dataB <- dataA[, c("P1", "xyz", "acdc")]
```

Or if there are some sequence of column names based on index, subset the column names with a position index and use that to select the columns

```
dataB <- dataA[, colnames(dataA)[c(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,40,43,46,47,48,49)]]
```

To make this easier, all the sequence can be abbreviated with `:`

```
dataB <- dataA[, colnames(dataA)[c(1:2, 4:10, 40, 43, 46:49)]]
```